# Find the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of integers satisfying $0\le a,b,c\le1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Find the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of integers satisfying $0\le a,b,c\le 1000$ and
\$$(a+b+c-1)(a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca)) \equiv 3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \pmod{1001}$$

I am totally clueless how to solve this, as I am new to number theory.
So, any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that we can write your congruence as $$(a+b+c-1)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\equiv3(ab+bc+ca)\pmod{1001}$$

Comment: This will be easy to.solve?

Comment: I feel that there should be a quick way of doing this (recognise that $1001=7\times11\times13$) but I can't see it yet.